# PHP: Remove url parameters on click

Tags: php, url, replace, str-replace

I have a url that in the worst case scenario looks like this `website.com/clothes/women/type/tshirts/brand/nike/color/red/size/s/price/0-29`

This is created by clicking on links that will filter the results starting from `website.com/clothes/women`. The problem is how can I reverse it ? I show all the filters clicked with a `X` near it, so when clicked, a certain filter will be deleted and the page refreshes. If I delete the color filter, `/color/red` or `color/red/` must be deleted from the url.

How can this be done ? I tried with `str_replace()` but with no luck.

Just an input and I will find the way.

Thank you.

Comment: @meagar: what is the difference actually? Why is it worse than `?type=tshirts&...`?

Comment: @meagar I don't know what you mean, this is a query string, it's just formatted with .htaccess so it does not look like ?type=tshirts&brand=nike&... Can you suggest a better one ?

Comment: @C.Ovidiu use POST and session data with cookies like every other site on the planet.

Comment: @Deryck: it's actually the terrible advice (not to say it's silly). Check amazon and ebay

Comment: @meagar: that's how we treat it conventionally. URL RFC doesn't state it is a K-V pairs. A little quote: "The query component contains **non-hierarchical** data". So from standards perspective - using query fragment is not better

Comment: @zerkms I didn't look closely enough; I thought it was just an arbitrary series of `key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3...` but you're right, it specifically looks like it gets progressively more specific.

Comment: @meagar So can I leave it like this ? I don't mind changing it, but I always thought that this is better for readability and also SEO.

Comment: It's fine the way it is, though overly long. You might consider something like `/women/shirts/nike/red` instead of `clothing/women/type/shirts/brand/nike/color/red`; you're stuffing your URL with a bunch of extra terms that are potentially redundant.

Comment: @meagar I'd like to do it that way, but the order of the filters is random so it's impossible to do, at least in this case. If you have a suggestion on how to accomplish i will be more than happy to implement it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @meagar How would that work if you have a brand whose name matches one of the other attributes, e.g. `brand=red`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `str_replace()` should work:

```
function remove_filter($url, $type, $value) {
    return str_replace("/$type/$value", "", $url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a job for `str_replace` or regexes.

Use `explode` to put the components of the path into an array.  Manipulate the array.  Reassemble the path with `join`.